# Pass Parameters to views via Ajax

Tags: 7, views, ajax

While viewing a views generated page, like for instance a taxonomy term page, is there a way to update the views generated content by passing it some parameters, like for instance a new taxonomy term.

The purpose of this would be to update a view page content via an ajax request.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily execute and render a view with arguments in a custom module.

I would:

1 - Set up some JS code to trigger an AJAX call to the server

2 - Use `hook_menu()` to define a custom menu callback on a specific URL, ie: `/views/ajax/view_name/view_display/view_arguments`

3 - Create your callback function()

4 - Load and render the view with arguments: (this is From Views 2 API):

```
$view = views_get_view('foobar');  // get the view named `foobar`
$view->set_display('page_1');  // Set the view display you want to use
$view->set_arguments(array($foo));  // Pass an array containing one or several variables you want to use as arguments in the view
$result = $view->render(); // Returns HTML
```

5 - Return your result in JSON (practical sometime if you want to pass more information than the view itself). You can use `drupal_json_output()` in D7.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript I ended up using to load the views block with ajax and pass in the contextual filter from the href value of a list of links I created on page. Hope this helps someone!

```
function getInfo(args) {

  $.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      view_name: 'agent_lookup',
      view_display_id: 'agent_lookup_block', //your display id
      view_args: args,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response[1] !== undefined) {
        var viewHtml = response[1].data;
        $('#ajax-target').html(viewHtml);
        //Drupal.attachBehaviors(); //check if you need this.
      }

    },
        error: function(data) {
         alert('An error occured!');
        }
  });
}



$('.ajax_button').once().click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var the_id = $(this).attr('href');
    noSlashes = the_id.replace(/\//g,'');
    getInfo(noSlashes);

});
```